# How to say something “gets old fast”?

Tags: traducción, modismos

Describing something as '[getting old fast](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/110264/98507)' is a very common phrase in English to describe something as tedious, but it has the nuance that the thing may not be boring initially. Is there a natural equivalent in Spanish?

Comment: **This user is actively trying to improve their posts in an effort to remove a ban that prevents them from asking new questions. If you consider this question is now worthy of a chance, please consider answering and/or upvoting it, or help the user improve even more the question.**

Comment: Mmm I see you changed the question completely to a different one. Normally it is advised to not do so, and instead posting a new one. But since you mentioned in Meta you are blocked from asking it makes sense. In any case, and regarding the question itself, what did you find when trying to find an answer to this?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' I think we should allow this in these cases. The question ban is too strict: you have to *improve existing questions* instead of asking new, better ones. But the only way to improve a completely off-topic question is to completely change it. I do not agree with the question ban being so strict, but the only thing we can do is be permissive with these kind of changes...

Comment: @wimi yes, I agree in this case (and that's why I commented)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' [I agreed with Arunabh](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4358/12637) that they could completely change the question if it had no answers yet. I've taken care of previous existing comments nonetheless, so they could "reset" the question under my supervision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Colombia we would say

> Esto se esta poniendo cansón/mamón.

That would be used when initially something is ok but quite fast is not fun anymore and it translates "this is becoming boring"

Another way could be

> (ya) me estoy cansando de esto.

that translates "I'm already getting tired of this." and the unpolite way would be

> ¡me mamé de esto! / [#YaNosMamamos](https://twitter.com/hashtag/yanosmamamos?src=hash) / ¡me mamé de esta pendejada! (*)

(*) Use with caution

Answer (score 3):

I think the most common way to say that in Spanish is:

> **Cansar rápido.**

You can find the following definition for the word *cansar*:

> **[cansar](https://dle.rae.es/cansar)**
>
> Del lat. *campsāre* 'doblar un cabo', 'desviarse del camino', 'virar', y
> este del gr. *κάμψαι kámpsai*.
>
> 4. tr. Hacer que disminuya el interés de alguien. U. t. c. intr.

That fourth meaning says "To make someone's interest diminish", which is what *getting old* implies.

An example of usage:

> *Y sobre la televisión, pues... es algo peligrosa, porque la gente se cansa muy rápido de ver la misma cara.*
>
> Tiempo, 28/05/1990 : "Terranova" (Spain).

The example implies that people may be interested in watching a new face on television, but that new face may get old very fast.